# IP Helper address on same VLAN with Cisco

Tags: ip, dhcp, vlan

Is it a good habit to use a `ip helper address` on Cisco, or any similar ip helper, when the DHCP is on the same subnet as the client/server.

Comment: No - what purpose would it serve?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm wondering. I've got some old documentation from a previous sysadmin, and he recommend using ip helper-address on the cisco switch, but I highly doubt there is a point to do so, especially when the device is on the same subnet.

Comment: If you mean that the DHCP clients are on the same physical network segment then no, I don't see any value in configuring a DHCP relay agent on your router.

Comment: Makes sense. Maybe you should add this as an answer ? I just wanted to have confirmation to be sure. Doesn't seem anyone asked before that here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. When DHCP server and client are on the same segment a helper/DHCP relay serves no purpose.